# Continously running a PHP script waiting for videos to trancode

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, ffmpeg

I'm making a transcoding server which uses FFMPEG to convert videos to flv. After user uploads a video it's queued for processing in amazon Simple Queue Service. System is linux ubuntu.

Instead of running CRON each 1min I wonder if it would be possible to continously run several PHP scripts (dowload queued files, process downloaded etc). Each of them would have its own queue which would be read every 10s or so looking for new tasks.

My question is:

How to detect if the script is already running? I'd run CRON each 1min and if one of the programs would not be running I'd load it again. How stuff like that is done on linux? PID files?

thanks for help,
ian

Comment: Have you considered using ajax to test if it has completed uploading?

Comment: @Trevor That doesn't really have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this with only pure-PHP, I would probably go with a solution based on [**gearman**](http://danga.com/gearman/) *(quoting [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Gearman))* :

> Gearman is an open source application
>   framework [...]. 
> Gearman is
>   designed to distribute appropriate
>   computer tasks to multiple computers,
>   so large tasks can be done more
>   quickly.

It works well with PHP, thanks to the [gearman](http://fr.php.net/gearman) extension, and will deal with most of the queuing stuff for you.

Note that it'll also facilitate things when you have more videos to transcode, making scaling to several servers easier.

Comment: Hi, I'm using amazon SQS, which, after adding some code, provides me the same functionality as gearman (and one less think to worry about: machine with gearman). Anyway, changing to gearman won't resolve my problems how to keep continously running the application, waiting for new tasks to come from the queue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use PID files
Or temporary table, or memcache, e.t.c.

But I do like this:
By cron runs script that execute convert video, and it check if process is terminated or not
This cron script get movie what needs to convert from database or file

Answer (score 0):

PHP's PEAR repository has a [`System_Daemon`](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) class for creating daemons out of PHP. I've used it for a couple systems with good results.

Comment: Tahsnk! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a similar script specifically for this issue

Check: https://github.com/SirNarsh/EasyCron
The idea is to save PID of the script to a file, then check if the process is running by checking /proc/PID existence